# How does using a random hash in URLs improve security for reources?

Tags: security

I've noticed that Gmail uses a random string of characters to identify each e-mail in the URL.

Is this much more secure than simple auto-incrementing ID's?

If you do not have access to an ID, either way the server will deny you access. It can return the same error message whether or not the ID exists or not. With passwords this is different, since it takes time to try to different hashes - for a resource, I don't see the benefit aside from possibly taking longer to find an email that exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this string is random. I just had a look at several of my gmail inboxes and there was a definite pattern to the numbers. For this reason and the reason you've stated already, I don't think the ID's in the URL are intended to improve security.